# How to do a hit test on line segments drawing using UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath

Just wondering if there is any way of doing hit test on open ended shapes like line segments drawn using UIBezierPath.

Comment: Googled "UIBezierPath hit test". This was top: http://oleb.net/blog/2012/02/cgpath-hit-testing/

Comment: thanks it is bit hard for me to follow as i do not know objective C, but could  picked up few things.